# Swift: How to remove default auto first responder assignment

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2

The app automatically assigns the first control in the document outline to the *first responder* automatically after the app launch (See reset button in the screenshot below).

[image]

I did not assign any control to be the first responder in my code. How to disable this behavior using swift?

I have referred and tested some Objective-C methods about resigning first responder but no effect.

Any hint or comment is appreciated and thanks for your time viewing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of investigation, I finally realize that it is my own problem. The button is auto-focused because I turned on the full keyboard access on my Mac (See screenshot below). It behavior commonly after I set it to the *Text box and lists only*.

[image]